# Keep variable in RAM between PowerShell sessions

Tags: powershell

I've seen ways to keep data in files in order to preserve it between sessions, but I'm looking for a way to somehow keep it in memory. I want to to be able to set the variable, close the session, open a new session, and access the variable without the use of any files.

Comment: Variables have scope https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2,  and you are bound by that feature implementation. Once you close the session, all context of that session is gone, by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a program exits, all of its data is reclaimed from memory unless it stays open in the background, which hardly counts as a different session. What you're asking for is impossible to the extent of my knowledge.